# Evaluating $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x - \sin x \cos x}{\tan x - x} $ without L'Hospital or series expansion

Tags: limits-without-lhopital

Evaluate the limit without using L’Hospital’s rule and without using series expansion

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x - \sin x \cos x}{\tan x - x} $$

Comment: You've been here long enough that you should have anticipated this question, but ... *What have you tried?*

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite $\sin x \cos x$ as $\frac{1}{2}\sin 2x$ and then use Taylor expansion for it and $\tan x$.

Comment: The Taylor expansion and Hospital they are just the same.

Comment: I don’t agree. When using Taylor expansion, you don’t change the function inside limit, just assume it’s behavior near given point. And it has less requirements, then L’Hospital rule.

Answer (score 0):

Since

1.$
\sin x\cos x = x - \frac{2}
{3}x^3  + o(x^3 )
$

2.$\tan x=x+\frac{x^3}{3}+o(x^3 )$
You have that
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{{x - \sin x\cos x}}
{{\tan x - x}} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{{\frac{2}
{3}x^3  + o(x^3 )}}
{{\frac{1}
{3}x^3  + o(x^3 )}} = 2
$$

Answer (score 0):

The limit can be expressed as $$\dfrac82\dfrac{\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{2x-\sin2x}{(2x)^3}}{\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\tan x-x}{x^3}}$$

Now use [Are all limits solvable without L'Hôpital Rule or Series Expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387333/are-all-limits-solvable-without-lh%C3%B4pital-rule-or-series-expansion)